# Exc_Bad_Instruction Error when retrieving JSON data

Tags: ios, json

I have written simple code to get JSON data from a News API. I have an API Key and implemented it as following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = URL(string: " https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=af5f94cdf07e42ee877a3f2c2199d097")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "user_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
        (data, response, error) in if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let articles = myJson["articles"] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let titles = articles["title"] {
                            print(titles)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

However, with this, the app crashes and gives the error: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)"
Why does this error occur and how can it be resolved?

Edit: Removing the space in the url seemed to fix the problem, but now the console doesn't print(title) (nothing shows up on the console)

Comment: `url` is probably `nil`.  Likely because you have a space at the beginning of it

Comment: Pro-trip, don't post your API key